# Objective-C - How to replace space with '+'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I add a plus(+) sign when there is a space in a sentence?

Example:

```
Hello how are you doing
```

What I want is:

```
Hello+how+are+you+doing
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello how are you doing";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method from NSString class

Answer (score 0):

You can just do something like this:

```
NSString *helloWorld = @"Hello How are you doing";
NSString *alteredString = [helloWorld stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"` is specifically what you are looking at here.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableString *nstring = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Hello how are you doing"];

   NSString *newString =  [nstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment: Not that it's wrong, but why an NSMutbaleString?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yet he doesn't modify the string itself but creates a new, altered instance. For that, a mutable string is not needed.

Comment: @H2CO3, oh, I should go back to bed.

Comment: @vikingosegundo or perhaps OP needs to fix his code ;)